# Storing and Displaying Live Stats

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, statistics

Say we are a site receiving massive amounts of traffic, Amazon.com size traffic. And say we wanted to display a counter on the home page displaying the total number of sales since December the first and the counter was to refresh via ajax every 10 seconds.

How would we go about doing this?

Would we have a summary database table displaying the total sales and each checkout would +1 to the counter and we would get that number every 10 seconds? Would we COUNT() the entire 'sales' table every 10 seconds?? Is there an external API I can push the stats off to and then do an ajax pull from them?

Hope you can help, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you do, do not re-COUNT everything every 10 seconds. Why not to have a cronjob, which does the counting of data every 10 seconds? It could take current time-10 seconds and in slave database add the difference to current count ?

Still 10 seconds sound bizarre. Every minute, mm?

Comment: Cron cannot be scheduled at seconds level.  Standard cron goes to a minute granularity

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but instead of to a slave database, can be stored in memcached. I feel the real time update of money raised/sales is important as I have explained in my post above.

Comment: @GundarsMēness Why would one reinvent the way a great tool works when one can for example trigger on insert incrementing the counter in the database as a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

If your site is ecomm based, in that you are conducting sales, then you MUST have a sales tracking table somewhere. You could simply make the database count part of the page render when a user visits or refreshes your site.

IMO, there is no need to ajax this count as most visitors won't really care.

Also, I would recommend this query be run against a readonly (slave) database if your traffic is truly at amazon levels.

Comment: I'm just using Amazon as an example but yes I do have a sales table with all sales history in. Surely if we were to count() the entire table every time we refreshed on a site the size of Amazon it would be a terrible load on the database? Unless we were to cache the sales stats in memcached and refresh that every 10 seconds or something?

Comment: @user1104791: Is the number of sales really that critical to your user-base? If so, I would probably go for every 10 minutes, generate the count and store it in memcache as you suggested, otherwise do it every 30 minutes or hour.

Comment: A better example would probably have been a large scale charity holding a 24 hour special event for fundraising. The viewer would be able to see the total money raised increasing at a rapid pace in real time encouraging them to donate also.

Comment: @user1104791: Ahhh that is a whole different user experience, you should have mentioned that in your OP. As I mentioned before you could setup the AJAX approach, but have it execute the query against a slave mysql server, this way you don't add to the load of your read-write database.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was having difficulty coming up with a good example before. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I would put triggers on the tables to manage the counter tables. When inserting a new sale the sum table would get the new value added to the row for the current day. That also gives sales per day historically without actually querying the big table.

Also, it allows for orders to be entered manually for other dates than today and that day get updated statistics.

As for the Ajax part that's just going to be a query into that sum table.